# Matching multiple comma separated values in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Based on values in first two columns I need to populate third column (marked with yellow).

### [image]

Is something like this possible without using VB?

Comment: I can suggest you UDF (VBA) will work as a Excel Formula without any problem, please confirm whether you need this or not?

Comment: Are there always 4 possibilities with 2 winning teams or does the numbers vary?

Comment: It is always 4 participants, 2 winners and 2 losers, and I need it without VBA

Comment: @user3760419, the solution what I was suppose to suggest can work with any combination 4 +2 or 5+3 or with words and number even and it's very simple to use !

Comment: @RajeshS, unfortunately VB is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

If there are always four teams with two winners and two losers, there is a relatively simpler solution:

```dart
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1&",",LEFT(B1,FIND(",",B1)),""),MID(B1,FIND(",",B1)+1,LEN(B1))&",","")&",",",,","")
```

---

Yes, this is possible with just an array formula. It's not exactly simple, though.

The following is a general solution that works with any number of participants and winning teams:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `C2` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the table column (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=
TEXTJOIN(
  ",",
  TRUE,
  IF(
    MMULT(
      --(
        TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2&",",",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2)+1)),(ROW(INDEX(C:C,1):INDEX(C:C,(LEN(A2)+1)/2))-1)*(LEN(A2)+1)+1,LEN(A2)+1))
        =TRANSPOSE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2&",",",",REPT(" ",LEN(B2)+1)),(ROW(INDEX(D:D,1):INDEX(D:D,(LEN(B2)+1)/2))-1)*(LEN(B2)+1)+1,LEN(B2)+1)))
      ),
      ROW(INDEX(C:C,1):INDEX(C:C,1+LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))))
    ),
    "",
    TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2&",",",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2)+1)),(ROW(INDEX(C:C,1):INDEX(C:C,(LEN(A2)+1)/2))-1)*(LEN(A2)+1)+1,LEN(A2)+1))
  )
)}
```

Note that `TEXTJOIN()` is only available in Excel 2016. In earlier versions of Excel, a poly-fill UDF is required. (See [this post](//superuser.com/a/1331555) for a basic one.)

**Explanation:**

coming soon

For now, though, hopefully the following partly evaluated version of the formula in `C2` might help:

```dart
{=
TEXTJOIN(
  ",",
  TRUE,
  IF(
    MMULT(
      --(
        {"A";"B";"C";"D"}
        ={"A","C"}
      ),
      {1;2}
    ),
    "",
    {"A";"B";"C";"D"}
  )
)}
```

Comment: The explanation will have to wait until after I get some sleep ;-)

Comment: Wow, tnx Robin! I will check if 2016 will be avaliable. As I always have 4 teams with 2w and 2l could the solution be simplified so that it can run without text join and without VB?

Comment: @user3760419 You just caught me ;-) Yes it can be simplified so it doesn't use `TEXTJOIN()`. I don't understand what you mean with *"without VB"* as there is no VBA unless you don't have Excel 2016. Unless that's what you mean :-) PS I've updated the answer with the simpler non-general solution.

Comment: Perfect, now I have both great generic solution (in case 2016 is available) or a specific ones that will support all versions. Tnx !!!